# Imprimir caracteres especiales como la barra inclinada en PHP

Tags: php, char

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$imprime = \\Server1almacen$;
echo: $imprime;
```

Me imprime en pantalla esto:

```
Server1almacen$
```

y necesito imprimir esto:

```
\\\Server1\almacen$
```

Como verán he tenido que agregar una **barra inclinada adicional** adicional para que en pantalla salgan las 2 barras quizás no lo ven por que se ven en código así: `\\\Server1\almacen$`

No se por que se borran los caracteres especiales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La barra inclinada es un caracter especial, tienes que "escaparlo"

```php
<?php
$imprime = '\\\Server1\\almacen$';
echo $imprime;

/* Resultado: \\Server1\almacen$ */
?>
```

Comment: tengo una consulta cuando hago update me borra las barras. por cada update me desaparece 1 barra hasta quedar sin barras

Comment: @IvanDiazPerez: ¿podemos ver la consulta? o algo más del problema real que tienes?

Comment: Nunca he tenido problemas con queries con direcciones de URLs, mira si es que no estas aplicando algun metodo "saneador" que te remueva los slashes

Comment: @AugustoM: No es un slash (`/`), sino un `backslash` = `\\` que normalmente se usa para escapar cosas